# Automate the process of exporting the default solution from Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

I am responsible for multiple Dynamics CRM environments where we have our customizations deployed.  What I would like to do is automate the process of exporting the default solution to the file system. From there I can compare the solutions from different environments.

Is there a way to do this via PowerShell or perhaps the Dynamics SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CRM 2011 SDK includes methods to [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.exportsolutionrequest.aspx) and [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.importsolutionrequest.aspx) solutions. When exporting the destination is a zip file in the file system.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the "XRM CI Framework" by [Wael Hamze](http://waelhamze.com/), which  has some PowerShell cmdlets that wrap some common operations that you can perform using the SDK.  The distro includes an "[ExtractCustomizations.ps1](https://xrmciframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Main/CRM2013/TFS2013/Xrm.Framework.CI/Xrm.Framework.CI.PowerShell/ExtractCustomizations.ps1)" script that probably does most of what you want already.

He's also published a blog post on how to "[Automate your Dynamics CRM Builds and Deployments with PowerShell](http://waelhamze.com/2013/08/20/automated-crm-deployments-powershell/)". In particular, you'd be interested in the `Import-XrmSolution` and `Export-XrmSolution` cmdlets, which wrap the [ImportSolutionRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.importsolutionrequest.aspx) and [ExportSolutionRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.exportsolutionrequest.aspx), respectively.

Links:

- Version supporting CRM 2013 SP1: https://xrmciframework.codeplex.com/ (source plus binaries)
- Version supporting CRM 2011: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/018d3312-cc36-469e-95eb-79e066b0aa64 (binaries only)